# How to build Qt 6.2.2 from source on Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, build, openssl

I've been trying to build Qt 6.2.2 from source. I downloaded the sources package from the online installer but it fails each time, each time with a different error. I've tried a variety of configurations such as:

```
configure.bat -static -release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -prefix "C:\Qt\6.2.2\Static" -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests

configure.bat -static -release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -prefix "C:\Qt\6.2.2\Static" -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-icu -no-opengl -no-openssl -skip qtwayland -skip qtquick3d -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtquicktimeline -skip qtshadertools -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qttranslations -skip qt3d -skip qt5compat -skip qtcharts -skip qtcoap -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtlottie -skip qtmqtt -skip qtopcua -skip qtscxml -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebview

configure.bat -static -release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -prefix "C:\Qt\6.2.2\Static" -no-openssl -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

I've tried using x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017, x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019,
and x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019

Here is one of the errors I've gotten using all config options then `cmake --build .`

```
[1424/8836] Building CXX object 
qtbase\src\network\CMakeFiles\Network.dir\Network_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
FAILED: 
qtbase/src/network/CMakeFiles/Network.dir/Network_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1424~1.283\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe  
/nologo /TP -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_BUILD_NETWORK_LIB - 
DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS_SINCE=0x060000 - 
DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII - 
DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_FOREACH - 
DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE - 
DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_USE_SYSTEM_PROXIES -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 - 
D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE - 
D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_WIN64 - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\network\Network_autogen\include - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\network -IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\network\kernel - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\6.2.2 - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\6.2.2\QtNetwork - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\network\..\3rdparty\zlib\src - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\corelib -IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\6.2.2 - 
IC:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\6.2.2\QtCore -IC:\Strawberry\c\include /DWIN32 
/D_WINDOWS /DNDEBUG -O2 -MD /W3 /wd4530 /wd4577 -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 - 
FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding  
-Zc:externConstexpr -Zc:wchar_t -guard:cf -std:c++17 
/YuC:/Qt/6.2.2/Src/qtbase/src/network/CMakeFiles/Network.dir/cmake_pch.hxx 
/FpC:/Qt/6.2.2/Src/qtbase/src/network/CMakeFiles/Network.dir/./cmake_pch.cxx.pch 
/FIC:/Qt/6.2.2/Src/qtbase/src/network/CMakeFiles/Network.dir/cmake_pch.hxx 
/showIncludes 
/Foqtbase\src\network\CMakeFiles\Network.dir\Network_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj 
/Fdqtbase\lib\Qt6Network.pdb /FS -c 
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\network\Network_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory(1764): error C2027: 
use of undefined type 'QSslCipherPrivate'
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\../../src/network/ssl/qsslcipher.h(56): 
note: see declaration of 'QSslCipherPrivate'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory(1763): note: while 
compiling class template member function 'void 
std::default_delete<QSslCipherPrivate>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const'
    with
    [
        _Ty=QSslCipherPrivate
    ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory(1873): note: see 
reference to function template instantiation 'void 
std::default_delete<QSslCipherPrivate>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const' being 
compiled
    with
    [
        _Ty=QSslCipherPrivate
    ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory(1802): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 'std::default_delete<QSslCipherPrivate>' 
being compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\../../src/network/ssl/qsslcipher.h(87): 
note: see reference to class template instantiation 
'std::unique_ptr<QSslCipherPrivate,std::default_delete<QSslCipherPrivate>>' being 
compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h(2168): 
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<char,38>' being 
compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\src\network\access\qnetworkaccesscache_p.h(127): note: see 
reference to function template instantiation 'std::array<char,38> 
QtPrivate::typenameHelper<QNetworkAccessCache::CacheableObject*>(void)' being 
compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h(2168): 
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<char,28>' being 
compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\../../src/network/access/
qnetworkreply.h(197): 
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::array<char,28> 
QtPrivate::typenameHelper<QNetworkReply::NetworkError>(void)' being compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h(2168): 
note: 
see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<char,31>' being compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\../../src/network/ssl/
qsslpresharedkeyauthentica 
tor.h(94): note: see reference to function template instantiation 
'std::array<char,31> 
QtPrivate::typenameHelper<QSslPreSharedKeyAuthenticator*>(void)' being compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h(2376): 
note: 
see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<char,30>' being compiled
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h(1587): 
note: 
see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<char,9>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory(1764): error C2338: 
can't 
delete an incomplete type
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory(1765): warning C4150: 
deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'QSslCipherPrivate'; no destructor called    
C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\../../src/network/ssl/qsslcipher.h(56): 
note: 
see declaration of 'QSslCipherPrivate'
[1426/8836] Building CXX object 
qtbase\src\tools\qvkgen\CMakeFiles\qvkgen.dir\qvkgen.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I've also downloaded the 5.15.x source from [here](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers) which I'm able to build without issues using the first configure command I posted.

I currently have Strawberry Perl 5.32.x, python 3.10, 3.9.x, and Cmake 3.22.1 installed  they're all in my path as well. Per [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-building.html) I meet the requirements. I confirmed the path is correct using where <insert_name.exe> which returns:

```
where perl.exe
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
where python.exe
C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
where cmake.exe 
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
```

As I was writing this I kept digging and found a ton of bug reports about this same issue. It seems to all come back to OpenSSL. I grabbed the OpenSSL source, I installed NASM and added it to my path. I configured and built OpenSSL with:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
nmake all
```

Once OpenSSL finished reconfigured Qt with it:

`configure.bat -prefix "C:\Libraries\QT-Static" -release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -I "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\include\openssl" -L "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\lib"`

This time it shows the following:

```
Qt Network:
getifaddrs() ........................... no
IPv6 ifname ............................ no
libproxy ............................... no
Schannel ............................... yes
OpenSSL ................................ yes
Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes
DTLS ................................... yes
OCSP-stapling .......................... yes
SCTP ................................... no
Use system proxies ..................... yes
GSSAPI ................................. no
Brotli Decompression Support ........... no
```

Then ran:

```
cmake --build . --parallel
```

It still fails but this time with a lot more errors, once again linking back to the OpenSSL issue. I thought maybe it had to do with the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD flag so I forced 17 instead of allowing MSVC to force latest but no luck. Has anyone managed to get 6.2.2 to build on windows 10, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your compiler to the latest VS2019 version (16.11) - see also https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-97999

Comment: You're a life saver, that did the trick. I also had an issue with Visual Studio Installer not showing 2019, I ended up having to purge the install folder as well as clean install 2019. I purged the Qt Source completely too, reconfigured and then built with 16.11 and it worked perfectly!